# How do I authenticate advanced services for service accounts?

Tags: http, google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, google-drive-api

I have a sheets bound google apps script file that is triggered by the installable trigger onFormSubmit(), which was set up by me. The script, therefore, always runs with my data, no matter who fills out the google form which I am collecting data from.

As a part of this script, the Drive advanced API is utilized, and I create and edit teamdrives using this advanced service.

I want to be able to use the Drive Advanced Service, with all of its authentication management and autocomplete features, while using a service account.

I've seen from other questions on this topic that there are libraries for the management and use of service accounts within Google Apps Script, but they require managing authorization tokens and such of the users which the service account acts on behalf of, and using them to access the API. Going this route, I will have to use the HTTP Interface for the Drive API rather than the Advanced Service, which isn't optimal, but still doable.

Is there a way to authorize advanced services such as the Drive API for a service account acting on behalf of a particular user of my G suite organization in my scenario?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll check those out.